# C swap Pointer Race Conditions

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, swap, race-condition

Im currently developing a C program which more or less is a unified (de)multiplexer where the user creates a mapping between input and output. While destinations are only held once and are available for all sources, a source can exist once or multiple times in different groups (but not twice in the same group)

Anyhow that is my context. So that groups are useful, I implemented a function that switches the group on user input.

The currently active group is hold by a pointer "activeGroup".

There is a thread for each output destination that waits for input and checks the mapping of the active group, therefore using the "activeGroup" pointer.

My test environment today used ca. 2kHz input, while end-user input could be way higher (like 1000kHz, considering inactive sources can also send data). There were no visible problems.

My question now:

Should I use an RWLock for the "activeGroup" pointer? Is the simple swap of the pointer atomically a problem? Generally I dont mind if one or hundred input packages go to the wrong destination for a brief fraction of a second, but could I somehow have a segmentation fault if the reading threads read in the absolutely wrongest of moments?

the only function that writes to the pointer:

```
bool activate_group(char *groupName){
    ... (get correct group to activate)
    if(newActive){
        if(activeGroup)
            activeGroup->isActive = false;
        // the only writing line to activegroup
        activeGroup = grp;
        grp->isActive = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

One of the two functions that access it (well pretty similar)

```
void forward_sender(...){

    if(activeGroup && (input = FINDCORRECTINPUTSOUCEIN(activeGroup->mappingList)){

        snd_params par;
        par.sockfd = sockfd;
        par.msg = buffer;
        par.len = len;
        sendMultipleByInput(activeGroup->mappingList, sender, &par);
    }
}
```

The other function sends directly, this one may send multiple times.

If activeGroup switches in between, sendMultipleByInput would simply not send, as it would not find a mapping between the device in the now new active mapping List.

If it could happen with current implementation, would I avoid it by simply accessing the activeGroup pointer once and copying the value into a local pointer?

That would minimize the chance if there is one, I guess?

As performance is the key factor in my program, Id like as much synchronization methods that could slow down or even lead to a deadlock (unlikely using rwlock prefering writer here, but still)

Thanks for any insight

Comment: Using locks can never lead to a deadlock assuming you acquire them in a consistent order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody has answered so far, so hopefully I can help.

To expand on deadlock comment, consider the classic example...

```
T1: A -> B
T2: B -> A
```

You can avoid the deadlock (`T1` and `T2` can both make progress) just by switching `T2`'s order to...

```
T2: A -> B
```

You *absolutely* should not avoid locks just to avoid deadlocks.  Your instinct is right about using an `rwlock` though, so it's still best to minimize the scope of critical sections.

Performance for locks shouldn't be a concern.  Most lock implementations will avoid entering the kernel.  If latency really is an issue though, there are a number of good spinlock implementations.

Not using explicit synchronization will almost **certainly** result in incorrect behavior.  Writing a pointer to memory *is* usually an atomic operation on most architectures (notably x86), but the order in which reads and writes happen across cores/processors is not defined.

For example, in your code...

```
bool activate_group(char *groupName){
    ... (get correct group to activate)
    if(newActive){
        if(activeGroup)
            activeGroup->isActive = false;
        // the only writing line to activegroup
        activeGroup = grp;
        grp->isActive = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and...

```
void forward_sender(...){

    if(activeGroup && (input = FINDCORRECTINPUTSOUCEIN(activeGroup->mappingList)){

        snd_params par;
        par.sockfd = sockfd;
        par.msg = buffer;
        par.len = len;
        sendMultipleByInput(activeGroup->mappingList, sender, &par);
    }
}
```

There are a number of different valid memory orderings.  In particular, nothing protects `mappingList` from being updated before `activeGroup`.  The actual order has almost nothing to do with the program order.  What's more, the compiler will always avoid memory reads and writes.  So the values are more than likely to stay in registers and not even touch memory.

**!!!DANGER ZONE!!!**

If lock-free programming is absolutely necessary C11 added lock-free [atomics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).  However, unless you fully understand the various memory ordering permutations, you will almost certainly get behavior you don't expect.

Comment: Is there a source that it certainly is incorrect behaviour? In my program context, i can live with misdirected packages for a brief moment, failure however is not an option

Comment: The best overall reference I could find was [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering) wikipedia page.  It has references for a number of good papers as well, including Paul McKenney's.  Even with relaxed consistency, an `rwlock` is still the best way to avoid failure.  You may want to look at C11 atomics though.

Comment: Thank you very much. C11 is not an option either, though :)